# Property in class header vs in class body

Tags: kotlin

I have an `abstract` `class` entity.

```
abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id", sequenceName = "id_sequence", allocationSize = 1000)
    var id: Long? = null

    @Version
    private var version: Int = 0


    @NotNull
    var createdDate = ZonedDateTime.now()!!
}
```

And I have a class(javax.persistence Entity ) that inherits  from `AbstarctEntiy`

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "query")
data class Query(
    var name: String?,
) : AbstractEntity()
```

Is there any difference between using `users` in class header and in class body as in the following two codes?

## 1

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "query")
data class Query(
    var name: String?,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var users : List<Username> = mutableListOf()
) : AbstractEntity()
```

## 2

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "query")
data class Query(
    var name: String?,
) : AbstractEntity() {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var users : List<Username> = mutableListOf()
}
```

Comment: the only difference I can think of is that 1 allows you to provide users in the constructor (using a default empty list if not provided) as well as via a setter, while 2 only via a setter

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between passing an item through the constructor, and setting it as a property because you are using a `data` class to hold those.

While in example 1 and 2 Kotlin is generating a getter and a setter for both the `user` and `name` fields, main benefits of using a data class only get leveraged for items passed through the constructor.

In Example 1, because it's a data class Kotlin overrides the 'copy', 'toString', 'hashCode' and 'equals' classes for BOTH the properties you're passing into the constructor. So just as an example, the 'toString' function would look like so in the decompiled java code

```
   @NotNull
   public String toString() {
      return "Query(name=" + this.name + ", users=" + this.users + ")";
   }
```

In Example 2, you only get this benefit for the `name` property you are passing into the constructor, but not for the `user` list. In this case, the `toString()` and all the other functions I mentioned would only take into consideration `name`

```
   public String toString() {
      return "Query1(name=" + this.name + ")";
   }
```

This is true for all the rest of `copy()` `hashCode()`, and `equals()`

If you care about Kotlin handling these for both `user` and `name` then pass both through in the constructor. Otherwise, it doesn't matter.